# DRY-ing up some rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an rspec spec test that has two sets of the same tests ([from 24 Pull Requests](https://github.com/24pullrequests/24pullrequests/blob/master/spec/mailers/reminder_mailer_spec.rb)). I thought I'd refactor the spec whilst I fixed something else.

Normally I just do a basic `each ... do` array to DRY things up:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ReminderMailer, type: :mailer do

  # Half the code yay! :D
  ['daily','weekly'].each do |time_format|
    describe time_format do
      let(:time_format) { time_format }
      let(:user) do
        mock_model(User, nickname:           'David',
                         email:              'david@example.com',
                         languages:          ['Ruby'],
                         skills:             [],
                         pull_requests:      double(:pull_request, year: []),
                         suggested_projects: [])
      end

      # How do I do this bit better?  
      let(:mail) {
        if time_format == 'daily'
          ReminderMailer.daily(user)
        else
          ReminderMailer.weekly(user)
        end
      }

end
```

I couldn't figure out how to use the time_format with the send command, so I could do something like:

```
let(:mail) { ReminderMailer.send(timeformat(user) }
```

How could I do this?

Comment: You could call the method by name since `time_format` is the same as both of the method names; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810429/call-a-method-by-name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The snippet you asked to re-write:

```
let(:mail) { ReminderMailer.send(time_format, user) }
```

Now, IMO using `each` to write specs is a bad practice. Why? Because rspec already provides idiomatic infrastructure to keep specs DRYed: use `before` and `shared_examples`. I'd write:

```
describe ReminderMailer, type: :mailer do
  let(:user) { ... }

  shared_examples "a reminder mailer" do |subject:, body:|
    it 'renders the subject' do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq(subject)
    end

    it 'renders the receiver email' do
      expect(mail.to).to eq([user.email])
    end

    it 'renders the sender email' do
      expect(mail['From'].to_s).to eq('24 Pull Requests <info@24pullrequests.com>')
    end

    it 'uses nickname' do
      expect(mail.body.encoded).to match(user.nickname)
    end

    it 'contains periodicity in body' do
      expect(mail.body.encoded).to match(body)
    end
  end

  describe 'daily' do
    let(:mail) { ReminderMailer.daily(user) }

    it_behaves_like "a reminder mailer", 
      subject: '[24 Pull Requests] Daily Reminder',
      body: 'today'
  end

  describe 'weekly' do
    let(:mail) { ReminderMailer.weekly(user) }

    it_behaves_like "a reminder mailer", 
      subject: '[24 Pull Requests] Weekly Reminder',
      body: 'week'
  end
end
```

Comment: Fantastic, even better than what I asked about :)